# ALAssetsLibrary accessing all photos 1000 + from camera roll app crashes

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, alassetslibrary

I want to access all photos from camera roll my code is working fine if i have few images in camera roll then app is working fine but if i have more than 1000 photos then app crashes here is my code

```
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

     [al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll

                      usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
     {
         NSMutableArray *arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         NSString *albumName = [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName];
         if (albumName !=nil) {


         [arrGroupsNames addObject:albumName];
         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
          {
              if (asset)
              {

                  UIImage *img=[self imageForAsset:asset];


                  [arrImages addObject:img];

              }
          }
           ];

         [arrGroups addObject:arrImages];
         }



         [self.tableVieww reloadData];

     }



                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {
         // User did not allow access to library
         NSLog(@"error");
      }
     ];
```

and here is the function which return image from ALAsset

```
-(UIImage*) imageForAsset:(ALAsset*) aAsset{

    ALAssetRepresentation *rep;

    rep = [aAsset defaultRepresentation];

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
}
```

Comment: You're out of memory... You've created 1000 images of unknown (and potentially huge) size

Comment: so whats the solution?

Comment: Only call your `-imageForAsset` when you need the image, and store the `ALAsset` in your array.

Comment: @ShehbazKhan, check my answer bud..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing all 1000+ `UIImage` in an array and you are out of memory. I have the same issue, mine was 2000+ images and using the implementation below works for me.

I also suggest, you use `[asset thumbnail]` when displaying images especially if it's just for `UITableViewCell` or for other purposes that do not require the full resolution of the image.

Here a solution:

```
//First you need to declare `ALAssetsLibrary *al` as a global variable in the class
//
//like this:
//
//.h
@interface YOURCLASS : UIViewController
{
  ALAssetsLibrary *al;
}

@end
//
//or inside your .m
//
@interface YOURCLASS () 
{
  ALAssetsLibrary *al;
}

---

// you need to do this to check if 'al' is already declared and to declare once
if (al == nil)
    al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    ...

    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
      if (asset)
      {
         /*//your code
          UIImage *img=[self imageForAsset:asset];

          [arrImages addObject:img];
        */

        //instead of storing the actual UIImage object just store the `asset` in your array
        //like
        [arrImages addObject:asset];

      }
    }];

    ...

} 
failureBlock:^(NSError *error) 
{
  // User did not allow access to library
  NSLog(@"error");
}];
```

---

In your table delegate `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  ...

  //you need to get the image using the stored asset
  //like:

  //cast what's inside the array
  ALAsset *asset = (ALAsset *)self.arrGroups[indexPath.row];

  //self.arrGroups[indexPath.row];
  //if just for example i dont know how you access your datas

  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];

  //getting the full resolution of the image
  //[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]]
  //
  //or you can simply use what you already have `[self imageForAsset:asset]`
  //cell.imageView.image = [self imageForAsset:asset];

  ...
}
```

Hope is is helpful for you, Cheers!

Comment: i have added your code. but getting image from asset in cellForRowAtIndexPath is not possible.. have u implemented it by yourself?

Comment: @ShehbazKhan, i stated it with my answer.. Mine was infact 2000 images.. Oh yes i reviewed my answer, i missed the type casting..

Comment: invalid attempt to access <ALAssetPrivate: 0x16fce9e0> past the lifetime of its owning ALAssetsLibrary
this is the error I am getting

Comment: what is the use of ALAssetsLibrary in cellForRowAtIndexPath??as i need just AlAsset only

Comment: can you please help me out as i am stuck in it

Comment: @ShehbazKhan, not sir, the `ALAssetsLibrary` is not in the delegate `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.. can you post you actual code? its hard to guess..

Comment: @ShehbazKhan, you did not declare `ALAssetsLibrary *al` as global variable.. that's the only problem now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84918/discussion-between-shehbaz-khan-and-0yeoj).

Comment: User 'aspectRatioThumbnail' rather than 'thumbnail' to get a slightly higher resolution version of each thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that be creating a `UIImage` for each photo in the users camera roll you're going to run out of memory. This can easily be 1000+ images, and using `fullResolutionImage` will get the largest version of the image.

To resolve this, instead of composing an array of `UIImage`'s, put the `ALAsset` in the array. Then create the `UIImage` from the `ALAsset` only when it's required on screen.

Comment: i have added your code. but getting image from asset in cellForRowAtIndexPath is not possible.. have u implemented it by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
        -(void)loadCameraPhotos{

            [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
            ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

             [al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll

                              usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
             {
                 NSMutableArray *arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                 NSString *albumName = [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName];
                 if (albumName !=nil) {


                 [arrGroupsNames addObject:albumName];
                 [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
                  {
                      if (asset)
                      {

                         // if (arrImages.count<7) {



                          //UIImage *img=[self imageForAsset:asset];


                          [arrImages addObject:asset];
                          //}else
                            //  *stop=YES;


                       }
                  }
                   ];

                 [arrGroups addObject:arrImages];
                 }


                 [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
                 [self.tableVieww reloadData];

             }



                            failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
             {
                 // User did not allow access to library
                 NSLog(@"error");
              }
             ];
    }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PhotoSelectionTableViewCell";
    PhotoSelectionTableViewCell* cell = (PhotoSelectionTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhotoSelectionTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class] ]){
                cell = (PhotoSelectionTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    NSArray *arrtemp=[arrGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.lblTitle.text=[arrGroupsNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.lblCount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)arrtemp.count];

    ALAsset *asset = (ALAsset *)[arrtemp lastObject];

    cell.imgViewThumbnail.image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];;

    return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt this solution.NSCache must be used if you want too many photos loaded asap you can see the detail in this repository https://github.com/johnil/JFImagePickerController